# C++14 casting to return type of member function - terse version

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, c++14

Please consider this as the simplest working example I got to do to expose my doubt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <typeinfo>

using DefaultType = uint32_t;

class point
{
public:
    DefaultType x( ) const  { return DefaultType( 0 ); }
    DefaultType y( ) const  { return DefaultType( 0 ); }
};

int main( )
{
    long    cast_me = 0xaaaaaaaa;

    auto    casted = static_cast< std::result_of< decltype( &point::x )( point ) >::type >( cast_me );

    std::cout << "cast_me (" << typeid( cast_me ).name( )
        << ") has been casted (" << typeid( casted ).name( ) << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

The point is that, in a given moment, I need to cast one independent variable (`cast_me` in the example) to another type that matches the return type of a given member function (`point::x()` in the example).

This line:

```
static_cast< std::result_of< decltype( &point::x )( point ) >::type >( cast_me )
```

works great, and my example program gives me:

```
cast_me (l) has been casted (j)
```

The only problem is that this is too much verbose, to the point of making something fairly simple to become illegible.

Would it be any nicest and concise way of reaching the same result without any performance hit or fire any hermeneutics discussion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vittorio's solution is of course correct and much more concise, but frankly this is the sort of thing that typedefs were made for:

```
class point
{
public:
    using ReturnType = DefaultType;
    ReturnType x( ) const  { return ReturnType( 0 ); }
    ReturnType y( ) const  { return ReturnType( 0 ); }
};

auto    casted = static_cast<point::ReturnType>( cast_me );
```

Comment: Hello @Nir Friedman. Thank you for replying. By using your solution I would have to change more than a dozen classes and adopt it as a coding pattern. Feasible and the final result is quite good looking.

Comment: @fljx For better maintainability, you may consider declaring the type alias as follows: `using ReturnType = decltype(std::declval<point&>().x());` You can now change the return type of `x()` as desired without having to modify two places.

Comment: @user2296177 That was just a typo that I left the constructors in the body as the same type as before. Edited. I think that the whole point is to define the function interface in terms of a typedef, not the other way around. Not to mention, that as written, it is enforced that `x` and `y` have the same return type, which your approach is a departure from. In short, I think what you are suggesting is less maintainable (and less readable).

Comment: @NirFriedman What you state makes sense, I do not disagree. From my point of view, the reason for that alias was to have a shorthand way when casting, thus I would have personally named it `CastType` instead of `ReturnType` and had the function return type be `auto`. For this specific example, it would be strange to have `x` and `y` be of different types. Additionally, `std::common_type<>` could be used in order to determine a proper cast type that depends on both `x` and `y`. For the record, I prefer this answer.

Comment: @user2296177 I see what you are saying, that is a reasonable take on it.

Answer (score 7):

You could avoid the `result_of` altogether like this:

```
static_cast< decltype(point{}.x()) >( cast_me )
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4jViB5HhMmpMQFys)

---

Note that if `point` is not guaranteed to be `DefaultConstructible`, you should use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) as follows:

```
static_cast< decltype(std::declval<point>().x()) >( cast_me )
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UOk5ERpxLXGWbMfi)

Comment: Might be worth noting the `std::declval` gives you a `prvalue` which could call a different function.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think it has to, you could do `declval<point&>` I believe.

Comment: @NirFriedman You're correct.  `declval<T&>` gives you a `T&`.

Comment: Thanks @Vittorio Romeo. This sounds good but I need to ask you, wouldn't this solution add a (slight) overhead of instantiating a temporary object with `point{}`? And at the right moment I can't assure `DefaultConstructible`.

Comment: @fljx There is no overheard. You aren't actually constructing a point, just checking the type of the expression. In fact, `std::declval<>()` is not even defined.